# Trying to use swiper js with npm but I can not( Pure JS

Tags: javascript, npm, swiper.js

I want to use swiper js for my project and I want to install it using npm. Many times there were errors with the installation, but after fixing the errors there were no errors, but the slider did not work. Before this I installed it using a cdn file and everything worked, but I want to use npm. Help please, I've been sitting all day trying to do this.

Here's my code:

```
import Swiper from "swiper";
import "../node_modules/swiper/swiper.css";
import "../node_modules/swiper/modules/navigation.css";
import { Navigation } from "swiper/modules";
const controlMain = async function () {
  await model.setDefault();
  document.querySelector(".main-spinner").classList.add("active");

  const topAuthorsMarkup = `
  <section class="top-authors">
  <h2 class="heading-secondary">Top authors</h2>
  <!-- Список слайдов -->
  <div class="swiper top-authors__list">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      ${model.state.default.topAuthorsNames
        .map((authorName, i) => {
          return `
        <div class="swiper-slide top-authors__item">
          <figure class="top-authors__author">
            <img class="top-authors__img"
                 src="${model.state.default.topAuthorsImgs[i]}"
                 alt="${authorName} image" />
            <figcaption class="top-authors__description">
              <h3 class="top-authors__name">${authorName}</h3>
              <p class="top-authors__text">
                ${model.state.default.topAuthorsDescription[i]}
              </p>
            </figcaption>
            <a class="top-authors__link" href="#"></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
      `;
        })
        .join("")}
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
</section>
`
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  // Swiper options
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
```

Here's [video](https://youtu.be/q187MIi_NAk)

Comment: We are happy to see you on Stackoverflow, PLEASE share the code as text not a video or photo file, not everyone can go through internal links, edit your question, and you can also read the topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Given the code you've shown, in the line `await model.setDefault` there is no `model`. It's never defined and will throw an error.

Comment: @connexo I imported it: import * as model from "../js/model";